# Joint query many to many relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have the following class in my models.py

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    creator = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

I am trying to return a QuerySet using 2 creator names.

For example, how would I filter for stories that have  creators: User 1 obj and User 2 obj?

I have read the Many-to-Many relationships docs and could not find anything. The closest solution I have reached was...

```
Story.objects.filter(creator__in=[1,2]).distinct()
```

but it doesn't do a joint query for both 1 AND 2, just 1 OR 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: for future reference: I could have simply chained .filter().filter() statements but the below answer may be more elegant of a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to us a Q object. I'd try something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Story.objects.filter(Q(creator=1) | Q(creator=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Q objects for this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Something like the following should do what you want:

`Story.objects.filter(Q(creator=1), Q(creator=2))`